# Implementation of Temporal Difference Learning in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, temporal-difference

The below code is my implementation of temporal difference learning. The agent who uses the TD algorithm plays more than 750,000 games against an agent that uses mini-max procedure to play the game, But the problem is the TD-agent does not learn... What is wrong with this implementation?

updateToNextState is called when the agent choose a next move.

```
public void updateToNextState(int[] currentState, double[] nextStateOutput) {
    double[] outputOfNext = nextStateOutput;
    double[] outputOfCurrent = getOutput(currentState);
    double[] error = getDifferenceOfOutputs(outputOfNext, outputOfCurrent);

    lastHandledState = currentState;

    for (int j = 0; j < layers[HIDDEN].neurons.length; j++) {

        for (int k = 0; k < layers[OUTPUT].neurons.length; k++) {

            double toBeUpdatedValueForJToK = BETA * error[k]
                    * eligibilityTraces.getEjk(j, k);
            layers[HIDDEN].neurons[j].updateWeightToNeuron(
                    layers[OUTPUT].neurons[k].getNeuronId(),
                    toBeUpdatedValueForJToK);

            for (int i = 0; i < layers[INPUT].neurons.length; i++) {

                double toBeUpdatedValueForIToJ = ALPHA * error[k]
                        * eligibilityTraces.getEijk(i, j, k);

                layers[INPUT].neurons[i].updateWeightToNeuron(
                        layers[HIDDEN].neurons[j].getNeuronId(),
                        toBeUpdatedValueForIToJ);

            }

        }
    }

    updateEligibilityTraces(currentState); 
 }



private void updateEligibilityTraces(int[] currentState) {
    // to ensure that the values in neurons are originated from current
    // state
    feedForward(currentState);
    for (int j = 0; j < layers[HIDDEN].neurons.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < layers[OUTPUT].neurons.length; k++) {

            double toBeUpdatedValueForJK = gradient(layers[OUTPUT].neurons[k])
                    * layers[HIDDEN].neurons[j].output;
            eligibilityTraces.updateEjk(j, k, toBeUpdatedValueForJK);
            for (int i = 0; i < layers[INPUT].neurons.length; i++) {
                double toBeUpdatedValueForIJK = gradient(layers[OUTPUT].neurons[k])
                        * gradient(layers[HIDDEN].neurons[j])
                        * layers[INPUT].neurons[i].output
                        * layers[HIDDEN].neurons[j]
                                .getWeightToNeuron(layers[OUTPUT].neurons[k]
                                        .getNeuronId());
                eligibilityTraces.updateEijk(i, j, k,
                        toBeUpdatedValueForIJK);
            }
        }
    }
}


 private double gradient(Neuron neuron) {
    return neuron.output * (1 - neuron.output);
}


  public void updateToNextWhenOpponentEndsGame(double[] outputOfEndState) {

    updateToNextState(lastHandledState, outputOfEndState);

}


    private double[] getDifferenceOfOutputs(double[] outputNext,
        double[] outputCurrent) {
    double[] differencesVector = new double[outputNext.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < outputNext.length; i++) {
        double difference = outputNext[i] - outputCurrent[i];
            differencesVector[i] = difference;

    }

    return differencesVector;
}
```

I have used [this link](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp440/handouts/pa4.pdf) as guide line. I have tried different values for ALPHA & BETA, amount of hidden neurons. Eligibility traces are initialized to 0.

Comment: Really hard for us to debug when we do not see the whole code. Is this backgammon? Are you sure there is nothing wrong in your game code? Also, I would have separated the concerns a bit. Separate the neural network code from the TD-learning code, and also kept the game logic code also separated. Then I could also have verified the  code pieces separately.    Seems to me like you have no clue where you bugs are. (I would also have implemented TD(0) before I did TD(lambda). Look at [Sutton & Barto]http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html) chapter 6.

Comment: These are already separated. I use it for two different games (checkers and 4-in-a-row), and i became sure there is no bug in games. If the game is finished, i call updateToNextState method with reward (1,0,0 for win; 0,1,0 for lose; 0,0,1 for draw) otherwise normally with next states output. And to get know whats is the current value of a state, i call other method which gives the output of a state through the network without updating the network.

Answer (score 0):

The problem mainly is that you cannot tune your neural network function approximator, and from what you said I can assume that "it does not learn", means that the algorithm does not converge.

This happens when we use using TD and NN together. And this happened to me previously, and I searched for it for a long time. The lesson that I have learned is as follows:

According to Richard Sutton: Do not try to use Neural Networks as function approximators, together with TD methods, unless you know **exactly** how to tune your neural network. Otherwise, this will cause lots of problems.

To know more about it find Sutton's talk on youtube.